# JNI in Dataflow

Tags: java-native-interface, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to use JNI in my Dataflow pipeline. The JNI uses C++ library that has a ton of external dependencies on other system libraries. What would be the best way to make sure that the libraries are where they should be in the operating system when a worker runs the DoFn that uses the C++ library?

I found that the [DataflowPipelineOptions.setWorkerHarnessContainerImage](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataflow/v1b3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/dataflow/model/WorkerPool.html#getWorkerHarnessContainerImage()) might allow me to specify custom docker image from the *Google Container Registry* that I could potentially install bunch of libraries on, but the documentation doesn't say much more. Are there any requirements for the docker image in terms of installed packages, entry points, etc...?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question ? I'm also interested in it.

Comment: Best solution I've got so far is to install all dependencies on Debian 8 (that's what the Google Cloud Dataflow workers use) add them to a zip file and upload to Google Cloud Storage. Then inside the `DoFn.setup()` method download the archive and unpack into `/usr/lib`. It's little messier then I'd like but it works.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/running-external-libraries-with-cloud-dataflow-for-grid-computing-workloads?

Comment: how often is this code invoked? you could always host it in a separate cluster and invoke it remotely as needed. (ie. grpc or similar)

Answer (score 3):

Apache Beam recently published an [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/subprocess) of calling sub-processes from a Dataflow worker. The solution [downloads](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/subprocess/utils/CallingSubProcessUtils.java#L48) the binary dynamically within the DoFn's @Setup [method](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/subprocess/ExampleEchoPipeline.java#L100) and then [executes](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/subprocess/ExampleEchoPipeline.java#L115) the binary for each record processed by the pipeline. The solution also handles [collecting](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/subprocess/kernel/SubProcessKernel.java#L180) the output from the process and propagating failures to the pipeline.